# Multiprocessing working in Python but not in iPython

Tags: python, qt, multiprocessing, ipython

I am running the following code in iPython:

```
import multiprocessing

def my_function(x):
    """The function you want to compute in parallel."""
    x += 1
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.map(my_function, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
    print(results)
```

in ipython QT console on Windows. However,  the code does not work -- the QT console just freezes up. The issue is specific to iPython (the code above should work for the regular Python 2.7).

Any solution to this?

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu. Must be an issue with windows.  Do you paste the code into Ipython?

Comment: Yes, I do paste the code.

Comment: does it work when you run it from another shell or IDE?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it in Spyder IDLE. It works there. Any idea how to make it work in the actual QT console?

Comment: I second @PadraicCunningham's comment. Works fine on Linux distributions (I'm using Debian).

Answer (score 22):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Note
>
> Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be
>   importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines
>   however it is worth pointing out here. **This means that some examples,
>   such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the
>   interactive interpreter**

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code in the QT console, or did someting else?

Comment: The FINAL answer. No more effort struggling trying to get multiprocessing.Pool working on Jupyter notebook.

Comment: The answer by @Maverick does work in both Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab, for both 'fork' and 'spawn' multiprocessing.

Answer (score 19):

At least in the current version of Jupyter Notebook (the successor of IPython) you can solve this by moving the target function to a separate module, and importing it.

I have no idea why this works, it's rather odd, but it does.

i.e. - in a `workers.py` file put

```
def my_function(x):
    """The function you want to compute in parallel."""
    x += 1
    return x
```

Then in IPython/Jupyter notebook put:

```
import multiprocessing
import workers

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(workers.my_function, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(results)
```

also - the if-main thingy doesn't seem to be needed.

[Credit: Gaurav Singhal](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac)

Comment: This works but it seems like the performance has no increase because it looks like still running in a single process/thread.

Comment: @JohnZhang I get different process id's when I run this (although sometimes I do get the same process). You can just add os.getpid()  to the worker.py (make sure to import os).

Comment: In my test, I will get MP if I run it in Python console. However, if I run it in Jupyter, it will be always 1 process. I think it makes sense since one Jupyter notebook is one process in Jupyter architecture (at least on Windows).

Comment: @JohnZhang have you used pool? I also use windows and I do get multiprocessing. Also it doesn't make sense, as every IDE or even console you use is one process, and they all spawn different processes.