# multiprocessing.Pool vs multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here is some test of `multiprocessing.Pool` vs `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` vs sequential version, I wonder why `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` version is slower than sequential version?

Is it true that `multiprocessing.Pool` is faster because it use processes (i.e. without GIL) and `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` use threads(i.e. with GIL) despite the name of the package `multiprocessing`?

```
import time


def test_1(job_list):
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    print('-' * 60)
    print("Pool map")
    start = time.time()
    p = Pool(8)
    s = sum(p.map(sum, job_list))
    print('time:', time.time() - start)


def test_2(job_list):
    print('-' * 60)
    print("Sequential map")
    start = time.time()
    s = sum(map(sum, job_list))
    print('time:', time.time() - start)


def test_3(job_list):
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

    print('-' * 60)
    print("ThreadPool map")
    start = time.time()
    p = ThreadPool(8)
    s = sum(p.map(sum, job_list))
    print('time:', time.time() - start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    job_list = [range(10000000)]*128

    test_1(job_list)

    test_2(job_list)

    test_3(job_list)
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Pool map
time: 3.4112906455993652
------------------------------------------------------------
Sequential map
time: 23.626681804656982
------------------------------------------------------------
ThreadPool map
time: 76.83279991149902
```

Comment: Python multithreading is less useful than you think it is.  The Global Instruction Lock (GIL) means that only one thread can use the Python interpreter at a time.  Since your code is pure python interpreter, nothing much is gained.  Multithreading works best when your threads are waiting for external resources.   Google "Global Instruction Lock Python" for more detailed info.

Comment: By the way, your test program is a really nice one!   Create a lot of work with very little data transferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tasks are purely CPU bound (no blocking on I/O) and are not using any extension code that manually releases the GIL to do large amounts of number-crunching without the involvement of Python-level reference counted objects (e.g. `hashlib` hashing large inputs, large array `numpy` computations, etc.). As such, the definition of the GIL prevents you from extracting *any* parallelism from the code; only one thread can hold the GIL at once and execute Python bytecode, and you go slower because:

1. You have to launch all these threads
2. They have to hand off the GIL between themselves to simulate parallel processing
3. You have to clean up all the threads

In short, yes, [`ThreadPool` does what it says on the tin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool): It provides the same API as `Pool`, but backed by threads, not worker processes, and therefore does not avoid GIL limitations and overhead. It wasn't even documented directly until recently; instead, it was indirectly documented by the `multiprocessing.dummy` docs that were even more explicit about providing the `multiprocessing` API but backed by threads, not processes (you used it as `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`, without the name actually including the word "Thread").

I'll note that your test makes `Pool` look better than it normally would. Usually, `Pool` will do poorly with tasks like this (lots of data, little computation relative to size of data), because the cost of serializing the data and sending it to the child processes outweighs the minor gains from parallelizing the work. But since your "large data" was represented by `range` objects (which are serialized cheaply, as a reference to the `range` class and the arguments to reconstruct it with), very little data is transferred to and from the workers. If you used real data (realized `list`s of `int`), the benefits from `Pool` would go down dramatically. For example, just by changing the definition of `job_list` to:

```
job_list = [[*range(10000000)]] * 128
```

the time for `Pool` on my machine (which takes 3.11 seconds for your unmodified `Pool` case) jumps to 8.11 seconds. And even that's a lie, because the `pickle` serialization code recognizes the same `list` repeated over and over and serializes the inner `list` just once, then repeats it with a quick "see that first `list`" code. I'd tell you what using:

```
job_list = [[*range(10000000)] for _ in range(128)]
```

did to the runtime, but I nearly crashed my machine just trying to run that line (it would require ~46 GB of memory to create said `list` of `list`s, and that cost would be paid once in the parent process, then again across the children); suffice to say, `Pool` would lose quite badly especially in cases where the data fits in RAM once, but not twice.