# Drop row if column entry contains NaN

Tags: python, pandas, performance, series

I have a series `s` that has entries that are lists, for example `[1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN]` or `[4, 5]`. These lists may contain NaNs as the last few elements, and I want to drop all entires in this series that contain NaN. I have so far used `s.transform(lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan(x).any() else x).dropna()`, but this takes over a minute on just 21 million rows, and I am eventually planning on doing this with tens of billions of rows, so I need something fast. Thank you!

To emphasize, each entry in the series *is a list, and so I cannot just use `pd.dropna()` because there are no entries that are NaN since are lists themselves. I want to delete the lists (entries) that CONTAIN NaN*. This is what the series `s` might look like: `pd.Series([1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN], [4, 5]...)`.

Comment: Added a updated solution after your update to question. does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify all index positions that are equal to `NaN` for the exploded data frame and can then filter the data frame for those that are not in the index array:

```py
ser = pd.DataFrame(data={"col": [[1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan], [3, 4, 5], [3, 9], [np.nan, 10]]})['col'] 

ser_exploded = ser.explode()
ser[~ser.index.isin(np.unique(ser_exploded[ser_exploded.isna()].index))]

--------------------------------------
1    [3, 4, 5]
2       [3, 9]
Name: col, dtype: object
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `multiprocessing`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def check_nan(s):
    return s.explode().isna().groupby(level=0).max()

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Do not remove this line! Mandatory
    # Setup a minimal reproducible example
    N = 10_000_000
    s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN], [4, 5]]).repeat(N)
    s = s.sample(frac=1, ignore_index=True)

    CHUNKSIZE = 10_000
    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1) as p:
        results = p.map(check_nan, (s[i:i+CHUNKSIZE] for i in range(0, len(s), CHUNKSIZE)))
    m = pd.concat(results)
    s = s[~m]
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

For 20,000,000 records:

```
[...]$ python mp.py
Elapsed time: 1.58 seconds
```

Note: without `mp`, the execution time is 6.07 seconds:

```
start = time.time()
m = s.explode().isna().groupby(level=0).max()
s1 = s[~m]
end = time.time()
print(f"Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: How would I use the multiprocessed version in a Jupyter notebook? Can't seem to get the `if __name__` part to work in a cell where the variables are all already loaded in.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935690/15239951). Change `if __name__ == '__main__'` by a function.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you convert it into a DF, explode, then drop all NA and finally concatenate it back to the list, as the original series

```
s.to_frame().reset_index().explode(0).dropna().groupby('index')[0].agg(list)
```

INPUT

```
0    [1, 2, 3, nan, nan]
1                 [4, 5]
```

RESULT

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1       [4, 5]
```

Comment: Updated question to be clearer.

Comment: @TanishqKumar, updated the response. does it work for you?

Comment: @TanishqKumar, you need to drop the NaN or the whole entry?

Comment: The whole entry!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, filtering rows using a mask which tests for NaN values should work

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan as NaN
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN], [4, 5]])
s = s[~s.apply(lambda list1: any(pd.isna(x) for x in list1))]
print(s)

1    [4, 5]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
from numpy import NaN
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN], [4, 5]])
```

You can use:

```
s2 = s[s.explode().notna().groupby(level=0).all()]
```

Or, with a list comprehension:

```
s2 = s[[pd.Series(x).notna().all() for x in s]]
```

output:

```
1    [4, 5]
dtype: object
```

Comment: The first solution gives the error `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)`.

Comment: @TanishqKumar can you provide a reproducible example that raises this error?