# Process from Multiprocessing not working well

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am getting started with `multiprocessing` and tried to do a simple code using `Process`, however the result is different from `Colab` and my local pc. It seem on my pc (using Windows and `Jupyter lab` via Anaconda) the process doesn't start. The code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def teste(a):
    print(a)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('ok')
    p = Process(target=teste, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print('b')
    print(p)
```

The result when running on Colab is:

"ok 
1
b 
Process name='Process-10' pid=3765 parent=493 stopped exitcode=0>"

However if I run on my PC is:

"ok 
b 
Process name='Process-10' pid=27844 parent=10844 stopped exitcode=0>"

It seems the comand `p.start()` is not working. What can it be?

Comment: I don't know what's happening to the output from the print(a), but you're code is running.  That's evident from the fact that `p.join()` succeeded and the `p` is print out as a stopped process with exit code 0.

Comment: on Windows, you generally need to use `from multiprocessing import freeze_support` then call `freeze_support()` when you start `__main__`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns by doing this it works, but only if I export the file as an executable script an run on VS Code for instance..Is there a way to run it usnig Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Getting mp to work on Jupyter is difficult on non-Linux systems.  I'm not sure if it works on Linux either.  Multiprocessing starts a new Python process, and that process needs a file to read.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50937362/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47313732/8508004) may also help anyone coming across this post because of tags and mention of Jupyter.

Comment: For Jupyter Lab you need to place function `teste` in a separate module and import it.