# Parallel scipy milp optimizing with multiprocessing

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing

I want to solve a linear programming problem using the [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html). Everything works in one process. If you try to do this in several processes, then everything works too.
However, if you first do optimization using multiprocessing, then without it, and then with it, then everything hangs. Any idea why?

if you run the code below, it will run for an infinite time:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint, milp

def task(identifier):
    c = -np.array([1., 2])
    A = np.array([[-1., 1], [-3, 2], [2, 3]])
    b_u = np.array([1., 12, 12])
    b_l = np.full_like(b_u, -np.inf)

    constraints = LinearConstraint(A, b_l, b_u)
    integrality = np.ones_like(c)

    res = milp(c=c, constraints=constraints, integrality=integrality)
    return res.x


with Pool() as pool:
    for result in pool.map(task, range(3)):
        print(f'Before: Got result: {result}')

print(task(4)) # if you comment out - everything works, otherwise it hangs

with Pool() as pool:
    for result in pool.map(task, range(3)):
        print(f'After: Got result: {result}')
```

Python version and Libraries:
Python 3.10.11, Numpy 1.24.2, SciPy 1.11.3

Who knows why such strange behavior and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code from the command line with a script containing:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint, milp


def task(identifier):
    c = -np.array([1.0, 2])
    A = np.array([[-1.0, 1], [-3, 2], [2, 3]])
    b_u = np.array([1.0, 12, 12])
    b_l = np.full_like(b_u, -np.inf)

    constraints = LinearConstraint(A, b_l, b_u)
    integrality = np.ones_like(c)

    res = milp(c=c, constraints=constraints, integrality=integrality)
    return res.x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.map(task, range(3)):
            print(f"Before: Got result: {result}")

    print(task(4))  # if you comment out - everything works, otherwise it hangs

    with Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.map(task, range(3)):
            print(f"After: Got result: {result}")
```

Result:

```
Before: Got result: [3. 2.]
Before: Got result: [3. 2.]
Before: Got result: [3. 2.]
[3. 2.]
After: Got result: [3. 2.]
After: Got result: [3. 2.]
After: Got result: [3. 2.]
```

If you are trying to run your code within Jupyter/IPython, there are known complications with using multiprocessing in these environments. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50937362/189418) for some possible solutions.