# python multiprocessing pool.starmap does not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using multiprocessing `pool.starmap` function. I discover a strange issue.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = multiprocessing.Pool()

NODE = [1,2,3,4];
PageRank = [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25];
Destination = [[2,3,4],[3,4],[1,4],[2]];

Data = zip(NODE,PageRank,Destination)
```

So I use `zip` function to create a data set `Data`, which is a list with each entry being a tuple of length 3. Then I call the function

```
p.starmap(MyFunction, zip(NODE,PageRank,Destination))
```

It works great.

However, when I type

```
p.starmap(MyFunction, Data))
```

It output empty list `[]`!!!! I really have no clue what is going on. I literally just replaced `zip(NODE,PageRank,Destination)` by `Data`, which should be the same thing, right?

Is that because I am using Jupyter notebook that causes this?

Comment: Both ways work fine for me when I actually write a Python script that executes both lines. It is true that [`multiprocessing` does not work well in interactive prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641475/multiprocessing-working-in-python-but-not-in-ipython/23641560), so it's possible that's the cause of the issue you're seeing in Jupyter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Both versions actually work for me an a regular Python interactive interpreter on Linux, as long as I define `MyFunction` in a script and import it, rather than defining it on the interpreter.

Comment: In case you are doing other things with the zip object, note that a it can only be iterated once. If by the time you use it in starmap you are already at the end of the iterator, an empty list is what you should expect.

Comment: Ah, I think @brentertainer is probably right.

Comment: @brentertainer  could you please elaborate more on it? I just start learning this. What do you mean by `"note that a it can only be iterated once"...Thanks!

Comment: And you can wrap it in a list to test if that is the problem, e.g. `list(zip(...))`. With a list, you can iterate as many times as you want.

Comment: @ftxx Do a search for the difference between an iterator and an iterable. Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration). Zip objects are the former, lists the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is only valid if

- you are using Python 3, and
- you are doing things with the zip object (e.g. debug printing) that do not appear in your post

In Python 2, `zip(...)` returns a `list`; however in Python 3, it returns a `zip` object (which is not the same as a list like you say in your post).

A zip object is an *iterator*, and so can only be iterated over once. After you reach the end of the iterator, any attempt to iterate over it again will yield nothing. For example,

```
>>> z = zip([1, 2], [3, 4])
>>> for x in z:
...     x
... 
(1, 3)
(2, 4)
>>> for x in z:
...     x
... 
>>> list(z)
[]
```

To speak on my second bullet point, I suspect you are doing something *seemingly* innocuous like printing all the elements of `Data` before you pass it as an argument to `pool.starmap`. If that is the case, you are exhausting the iterator, then effectively telling `pool.starmap` to apply `MyFunction` to absolutely nothing.

To fix this, you have three options.

1. Do it the first way you mentioned in which the zip object is created inside the call to `pool.starmap`.
2. Do not loop over `Data` prior to passing it to `pool.starmap`.
3. Cast the zip object as a list (`Data = list(zip(NODE,PageRank,Destination))`). Then it is an *iterable* and you can iterate over it as many times as you would like.

In my humble opinion, this issue is just a rite of passage for newcomers to Python. If it applies to you and you want to learn more, you should read up on the differences between an *iterator* and an *iterable*, perhaps starting with [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).