# How to make parallel processing work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I am trying to do parallel processing in python. I have a huge dataframe with more than `4M` rows. So as a sample given below, I would like to divide the dataframe(`df will be divided into df1,df2`) apply the same set of `transpose operations` on the different resultant dataframes. Thanks to Jezrael for helping me reach upto this level.Please find below my input dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
'readings' : ['READ_1','READ_2','READ_1','READ_3','READ_1','READ_5','READ_6','READ_8','READ_10','READ_12','READ_11','READ_14','READ_09','READ_08','READ_07'],
'val' :[5,6,7,11,5,7,16,12,13,56,32,13,45,43,46],
})
```

**code to divide the dataframe**

```
N=2  # dividing into two dataframes.
dfs = [x for _,x in df.groupby(pd.factorize(df['subject_id'])[0] // N)] # dfs is an iterable which will have two dataframes
```

**parallel processing code**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = []

def transpose_ope(df):                      #this function does the transformation like I want
    df_op = (df.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
            .describe()
            .unstack()
            .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
            .reindex(df['readings'].unique(), axis=1, level=0))
    df_op.columns = df_op.columns.map('_'.join)
    df_op = df_op.reset_index()

results.append(pool.map(transpose_ope, [df for df in dfs])) # am I storing the output correctly here?
```

Actually, I would like to append the output from each stage to a main dataframe.

Can you help me do this?  My code keeps running even for just some 10-15 records.

Comment: Not an direct answer for your question, but have you try to use: https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel

Comment: @QuantChristo - Unfortunately, I am in windows right now. Looks like it works only with Linux and Macos

Comment: @QuantChristo - Hi, Have you tried using this? When I tried one of the examples given in their docs, it still keeps running for `30000000 rows × 2 columns`. May I know for a dataframe of this size, how long should this take using `pandarallel`?

Comment: I've used it about 2 months ago, simple `applyparallel` and it worked fine, but it also had to be run on windows machine so I need to stop using it. There is also https://github.com/modin-project/modin , to check it you need only `import modin.pandas as pd`

Comment: Did you try their example and was it fast? like within 2-3 mins?

Comment: I did't check their examples.You can try to run for 3k, 30k rows and so on to see how it behaves. It could be a bug https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/issues/39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you use in map needs to return the object you want.

I would also use the more idiomatic context manager available for pool.

EDIT: Fixed import

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def transpose_ope(df):                      #this function does the transformation like I want
    df_op = (df.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
            .describe()
            .unstack()
            .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
            .reindex(df['readings'].unique(), axis=1, level=0))
    df_op.columns = df_op.columns.map('_'.join)
    df_op = df_op.reset_index()
    return df_op


def main():

    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        res = pool.map(transpose_ope, [df for df in dfs])

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

Not sure why you're appending a single list to another list...but if you just want a final list of [transformed(df) for df in dfs], map returns just that.

Comment: Okay, I guess it's `mp.Pool`.

Comment: Actually did you try running this at your end? It is still running for the sample dataframe.

Comment: Might be a main issue, depends a bit on your OS, I'll edit it into a __main__ and main(), see if it works.

Comment: Is there any issue with code, I mean the `transpose_ope` function?

Comment: Works fine on my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201157/discussion-between-ec2604-and-ssmk).

Comment: OP was using Jupyter Notebook + Windows. Recommended reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641475/multiprocessing-working-in-python-but-not-in-ipython/23641560#23641560