# python multiprocessing does not run functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I just want to see a simple code implementation of multiprocessing on windows, but it doesn't enter/run functions neither in *jupyternotebook* or running saved *.py*

```
import time
import multiprocessing
s=[1,4]
def subu(remo):
    s[remo-1]=remo*9
    print(f'here{remo}')
    return
if __name__=="__main__":
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=subu , args=[1])
    p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=subu , args=[2])
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
#     print("2222here")
print(s)
input()
```

the output by .py is:

```
[1, 4]
[1, 4]
```

and the output by jupyternotebook is:

```
[1,4]
```

which I hoped to be:

```
here1
here2
[9,18]
```

what's wrong with code above? and what about this code:

```
import concurrent
thread_num=2
s=[1,4]
def subu(remo):
    s[remo-1]=remo*9
    print(f'here{remo}')
    return
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
## or if __name__=="__main__":
##...    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results=[executor.submit(subu,i) for i in range(thread_num)]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(f.result())
input()
```

doesnot run at all in jupyter pulling error

```
BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I kinda know I can't expect jupyter to run multiprocessing. but saved.py also can't run it. and it exits without waiting for input()

Comment: Running on command line in linux I got the hoped for result. Could not reproduce.

Comment: Okay, edit that, not quite the hoped for. `here1\nhere2\n[1,4]`. The [9,18] wouldn't happen because the subprocess memory (either copy-on-write or an independent process) isn't seen by the parent.

Comment: @tdelaney so how to apply changes on parent with multiprocessing, and what about 'here1' and 'here2', why they don't happen?

Comment: I'm not a regular jupyter user but just poking around saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641475/multiprocessing-working-in-python-but-not-in-ipython/23641560#23641560) suggesting that the worker be placed in a separate module so that it can be imported by the subprocess.

Comment: As for changes back in the parent, you'll need some way to communicate from process back to parent. `multiprocessing.queue()` can be that channel. And `multiprocessing.Pool` can also. Since I don't know the jupyter part, i'm not sure about answering.

Comment: @tdelaney I kinda know I can't get multiprocessing with jupyter. and at first I was working with concurrent.future.processpoolexecuter, read reedit of this post agian

Comment: I posted a 100% untested answer. Just in case nobody else joins in, its something to try.

Comment: I jump into IDEs with the best intentions but always end up with vim and a dozen terminal windows open.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of potential problems. The worker function needs to be importable (at least on Windows) so that it can be found by the subprocess. And since subprocess memory isn't visible to the parent, the results need to be returned. So, putting the worker in a separate module

subumodule.py

```
def subu(remo):
    remo = remo*9
    print(f'here{remo}')
    return remo
```

And using a process pool's existing infrastructure to return a worker return value to the parent. You could

```
import time
import multiprocessing
if __name__=="__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        s = list(pool.map(subu, (1,2))) #here
    print(s)
    input()
```

Comment: I got ur point in how to treat with s list, and do u mean I can't get "here1' and 'here2' unless I treat them like an output of function?

Comment: I was worried about that. disappointing. Are you on Windows? Just searching "jupyter notebook multiprocessing windows" in that case is my only suggestion.

Comment: You need to get the calculation from `remu()` back to the parent. You could create a `multiprocessing.queue()` then create a `multiprocessing.Process()` and hand the queue down with the call.  `Pool` does that part for you. The return value of the worker function is pickled in the process, returned to the parent, unpickled, and then iterated back from the `map` call. `list` just turns that return value iteration into a list. I noticed in your example that initial values in `s` didn't matter. Of course that's just a toy example and you may need to do something different.

Comment: I didn't get the queue part, do I need `.queue()` for a purpose like, this example of getting handling a separate list. isn't the map enough?

Comment: You wouldn't use a queue if you use map.

Comment: and what about concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor? how do I run with that? that seems much easier, and it does remain in console even with input(), and also I tried ``` if __name__=="__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:``` and didn't work.

Comment: another question is that why in my code didn't run `print(f'here{remo}')` from function?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be that the process didn't run. It could be that the stdout inherited from the jupyter notebook is directed to nothingness.

Comment: the output by .py also is:

[1, 4]
[1, 4]