# Hung cells: running multiple jupyter notebooks in parallel with papermill

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter, papermill

I am trying to run jupyter notebooks in parallel by starting them from another notebook. I'm using [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to save the output from the notebooks.

In my scheduler.ipynb I’m using `multiprocessing` which is what [some people](https://andrewm4894.com/2019/04/27/parallel-jupyter-notebooks/) have had success with. I create processes from a base notebook and this seems to always work the 1st time it’s run. I can run 3 notebooks with `sleep 10` in 13 seconds. If I have a subsequent cell that attempts to run the exact same thing, the processes that it spawns (multiple notebooks) hang indefinitely. I’ve tried adding code to make sure the spawned processes have exit codes and have completed, even calling terminate on them once they are done- no luck, my 2nd attempt never completes.

If I do:

```
sean@server:~$ ps aux | grep ipython 
root      2129  0.1  0.2 1117652 176904 ?      Ssl  19:39   0:05 /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/python /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/ipython kernel -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-eee374ff-0760-4490-8ed0-db03fed84f0c.json
root      3418  0.1  0.2 1042076 173652 ?      Ssl  19:42   0:03 /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/python /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/ipython kernel -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-3e2f09e8-969f-41c9-81cc-acd2ec4e3d54.json
root      4332  0.1  0.2 1042796 174896 ?      Ssl  19:44   0:04 /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/python /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/ipython kernel -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-bbd4575c-109a-4fb3-b6ed-372beb27effd.json
root     17183  0.2  0.2 995344 145872 ?       Ssl  20:26   0:02 /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/python /opt/conda/anaconda/bin/ipython kernel -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-27c48eb1-16b4-4442-9574-058283e48536.json
```

I see that there appears to be 4 running kernels (4 processes). When I view the running notebooks, I see there are 6 running notebooks. This seems to be supported in the doc that [a few kernels can service multiple notebooks](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/how_ipython_works.html). “A kernel process can be connected to more than one frontend simultaneously”

But, I suspect because ipython kernels continue to run, something bad is happening where spawned processes aren’t being reaped? [Some say it’s not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641475/multiprocessing-working-in-python-but-not-in-ipython/23641560#23641560) using multiprocessing. [Others have described the same problem](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5261).

```
import re
import os
import multiprocessing

from os.path import isfile
from datetime import datetime

import papermill as pm
import nbformat

# avoid "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running"
# it seems papermill used to support this but it is now undocumented: 
#  papermill.execute_notebook(nest_asyncio=True)
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import company.config


# # Supporting Functions

# In[ ]:


def get_papermill_parameters(notebook,
                             notebook_prefix='/mnt/jupyter',
                             notebook_suffix='.ipynb'):
  if isinstance(notebook, list):
    notebook_path = notebook[0]
    parameters = notebook[1]
    tag = '_' + notebook[2] if notebook[2] is not None else None
  else:
    notebook_path = notebook
    parameters = None
    tag = ''
    
  basename = os.path.basename(notebook_path)
  dirpath = re.sub(basename + '$', '', notebook_path)
  this_notebook_suffix = notebook_suffix if not re.search(notebook_suffix + '$', basename) else ''
  
  input_notebook = notebook_prefix + notebook_path + this_notebook_suffix
  scheduler_notebook_dir = notebook_prefix + dirpath + 'scheduler/'
  
  if not os.path.exists(scheduler_notebook_dir):
    os.makedirs(scheduler_notebook_dir)
    
  output_notebook = scheduler_notebook_dir + basename 
  
  return input_notebook, output_notebook, this_notebook_suffix, parameters, tag


# In[ ]:


def add_additional_imports(input_notebook, output_notebook, current_datetime):          
  notebook_name = os.path.basename(output_notebook) 
  notebook_dir = re.sub(notebook_name, '', output_notebook)
  temp_dir = notebook_dir + current_datetime + '/temp/'
  results_dir = notebook_dir + current_datetime + '/'
  
  if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
    os.makedirs(temp_dir)
  if not os.path.exists(results_dir):
    os.makedirs(results_dir) 
    
  updated_notebook = temp_dir + notebook_name 
  first_cell = nbformat.v4.new_code_cell("""
    import import_ipynb
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/mnt/jupyter/lib')""")
        
  metadata = {"kernelspec": {"display_name": "PySpark", "language": "python", "name": "pyspark"}}
  existing_nb = nbformat.read(input_notebook, nbformat.current_nbformat)
  cells = existing_nb.cells
  cells.insert(0, first_cell)
  new_nb = nbformat.v4.new_notebook(cells = cells, metadata = metadata)
  nbformat.write(new_nb, updated_notebook, nbformat.current_nbformat)
  output_notebook = results_dir + notebook_name
  
  return updated_notebook, output_notebook


# In[ ]:


# define this function so it is easily passed to multiprocessing
def run_papermill(input_notebook, output_notebook, parameters):
  pm.execute_notebook(input_notebook, output_notebook, parameters, log_output=True)


# # Run All of the Notebooks

# In[ ]:


def run(notebooks, run_hour_utc=10, scheduler=True, additional_imports=False,
        parallel=False, notebook_prefix='/mnt/jupyter'):
  """
  Run provided list of notebooks on a schedule or on demand.

  Args:
    notebooks (list): a list of notebooks to run
    run_hour_utc (int): hour to run notebooks at
    scheduler (boolean): when set to True (default value) notebooks will run at run_hour_utc.
                         when set to False notebooks will run on demand.
    additional_imports (boolean): set to True if you need to add additional imports into your notebook
    parallel (boolean): whether to run the notebooks in parallel
    notebook_prefix (str): path to jupyter notebooks
  """
  if not scheduler or datetime.now().hour == run_hour_utc:  # Only run once a day on an hourly cron job.
    now = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
    procs = []
    notebooks_base_url = company.config.cluster['resources']['daedalus']['notebook'] + '/notebooks'
    
    if parallel and len(notebooks) > 10:
      raise Exception("You are trying to run {len(notebooks)}. We recommend a maximum of 10 be run at once.")

    for notebook in notebooks:
      input_notebook, output_notebook, this_notebook_suffix, parameters, tag = get_papermill_parameters(notebook, notebook_prefix)
      
      if is_interactive_notebook(input_notebook):
        print(f"Not running Notebook '{input_notebook}' because it's marked interactive-only.")
        continue
      
      if additional_imports:
        input_notebook, output_notebook = add_additional_imports(input_notebook, output_notebook, now)
      else:
        output_notebook = output_notebook + tag + '_' + now + this_notebook_suffix
      
      print(f"Running Notebook: '{input_notebook}'")
      print(" - Parameters: " + str(parameters))
      print(f"Saving Results to: '{output_notebook}'")
      print("Link: " + re.sub(notebook_prefix, notebooks_base_url, output_notebook))
    
      if not os.path.isfile(input_notebook):
        print(f"ERROR! Notebook file does not exist: '{input_notebook}'")
      else:
        try:
          if parameters is not None:
            parameters.update({'input_notebook':input_notebook, 'output_notebook':output_notebook})
          if parallel:
            # trailing comma in args is in documentation for multiprocessing- it seems to matter
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_papermill, args=(input_notebook, output_notebook, parameters,))
            print("starting process")
            proc.start()
            procs.append(proc)
            
          else:
            run_papermill(input_notebook, output_notebook, parameters)
            
        except Exception as ex:
          print(ex)
          print(f"ERROR! See full error in: '{output_notebook}'\n\n")
          
      if additional_imports:
        temp_dir = re.sub(os.path.basename(input_notebook), '', input_notebook)
        if os.path.exists(temp_dir):
          os.system(f"rm -rf '{temp_dir}'")
    
    if procs:
      print("joining")
      for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    
    if procs:
      print("terminating")
      for proc in procs:
        print(proc.is_alive())
        print(proc.exitcode)
        proc.terminate()
    
    print(f"Done: Processed all {len(notebooks)} notebooks.")
    
  else:
    print(f"Waiting until {run_hour_utc}:00:00 UTC to run.")
```

I'm using python==3.6.12, papermill==2.2.2

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 5.5.0
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
ipywidgets       : 7.2.1
```

Comment: Might not be relevant, but have you looked into `ipyparallel`? Link ~> https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Is there a requirement to necessarily run these notebooks from another notebook? I think it would be easiest to just write a bash script to execute the notebooks in parallel (or not as desired). You can also schedule the script using `cron` jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module? It seems like a better option for you instead of multiprocessing. It allows you to asynchronously spawn sub-processes that will run in parallel, this can be used to invoke commands and programs as if you were using the shell. I find it really useful to write python scripts instead of bash scripts.

So you could use your main notebook to run your other notebooks as independent sub-processes in parallel with `subprocesses.run(your_function_with_papermill)`.

Answer (score 0):

## The solution

I implemented a parallel Jupyter notebook executor using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` (which uses multiprocessing under the hood). If you want to adapt it to your code, here's the [implementation](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber/blob/0c7f7ac5a2a03b93402caabc00f473a54e9f15c3/src/ploomber/executors/parallel.py#L221). This is a general executor, so there are a bunch of things that do not apply to your use case.

If you want to use the library, here's a snippet you can use:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from ploomber import DAG
from ploomber.tasks import NotebookRunner
from ploomber.products import File
from ploomber.executors import Parallel

dag = DAG(executor=Parallel())


engine = None

NotebookRunner(
    Path('input.ipynb'),
    File('output-1.ipynb'),
    dag=dag,
    name='one',
    papermill_params={'engine': engine})


NotebookRunner(
    Path('input.ipynb'),
    File('output-2.ipynb'),
    dag=dag,
    name='two',
    papermill_params={'engine': engine})
```

*Note:* as of Ploomber 0.20, notebooks must have a "parameters" cell (you can add an empty one). [See instructions here.](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-parameterize.html)

## The explanation

These issues of executing notebooks in parallel (or notebooks inside notebooks come from the way papermill executes them. It spins up a kernel, and the kernel process is the one running your code; the papermill process only sends messages and waits for responses.

This became a problem in a recent project (I need to monitor resource usage) so I wrote a custom papermill engine that executes notebooks in the same process. This is another option you can try:

```bash
pip install papermill ploomber-engine
papermill input.ipynb output.ipynb --engine profiling
```

Or from Python:

```py
import papermill as pm

pm.execute_notebook('input.ipynb', 'output.ipynb', engine='profiling')
```

(or, you can change `engine=None` to `engine='profiling'` in the first example)