# Running 3 Jupyter Notebook simultaneous from another Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Exist a way to run multiple notebook's simultaneous from another one?

ex: i can run another notebook using this

```
  %run ./called_notebook.ipynb
  foo()
```

but if i do this:

```
  %run ./called_notebook.ipynb
  foo()
  %run ./called_notebook2.ipynb
  foo()
  %run ./called_notebook3.ipynb
  foo()
```

the code run the first one and wait until end to run the next one,

i need that run the first, run the second, run the third and wait end of these three

its this possible?

Comment: You can use [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) from inside your control script or control notebook. An example is [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/running-a-cell-in-a-background-thread/12267/3?u=fomightez) of kicking off one process & continuing on with others that you could probably adapt. You may also want to use `nbconvert` to execute the notebooks, see [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#parallel-nbconvert). You also may want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65571729/8508004) for suggestions posted there.