# Python program freezes when multiprocessing call follows sequential call

Tags: python, multiprocessing, vips

I encountered a strange problem with a Python program processing images with the `pyvips` library. Here is a simplified version of my problem.

I try to create a numpy array (coming from zeros in my simple example) several times (2 times in the example).

When I do it sequentially, everything is fine. When I use the `multiprocessing` module, it also works as it should. But during my tests I noticed **the program freezes when I perform these two runs rapidly one after another**. Hence the program below. When I run it, it freezes before the first "step 3" in the multiprocessing part.

I think it is linked to a garbage collection mechanism but I am lost here.

I'm using python 3.11.3 and pyvips 2.2.2 (with vips-8.15.1). I use Spyder with its IPython console on a linux machine (a Ubuntu 22.04 based distribution).

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import pyvips

def myfunction(useless):
    print("step 1")
    image = pyvips.Image.new_from_array(np.zeros((8, 8, 3)), interpretation="rgb")
    print("step 2")
    res = np.asarray(image)
    print("step 3")
    return res

def main(nbpool):
    srcrange = range(2)
    if nbpool == 0:
        res = list()
        for srcid in srcrange:
            res.append(myfunction(srcid))
        return res
    else:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(nbpool)
        return pool.map(myfunction, srcrange)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res1 = main(0)
    print("Now with multiprocessing")
    res2 = main(1)
```

Comment: where are you executing this script?

Comment: I use Spyder with its IPython console on a linux machine (a Ubuntu 22.04 based distribution). I'll add it to my question.

Comment: I think the problem might come from the kernel that spyder uses, which is an Ipython kernel. I have encounter problems with for example jupyter notebooks and similar pieces of code. I have tried your code just executing it using a python enviroment and works fine. In spyder I think it wil work if you split the file in two and import the function from the execution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641475/multiprocessing-working-in-python-but-not-in-ipython

Comment: I first tried to run it in a Python interpreter but it does not work (as pointed out by the first answer in your link!). Executing it in my python environment (`python3 script.py`) did not work on my side. But splitting the file in two and importing (second answer in your link) worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing might be due to the fact that the multiprocessing module doesn't play well with IPython or Jupyter notebooks. This is because these environments aren't fork-safe, and multiprocessing relies on the ability to safely fork the Python interpreter.

One way to potentially solve this issue is to use the `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` at the beginning of your script. This will make the multiprocessing module create a new Python interpreter for each child process, which can avoid issues with forking in environments that aren't fork-safe.

Here's how you can modify your script:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import pyvips

# Set the start method for multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')

def myfunction(useless):
    print("step 1")
    image = pyvips.Image.new_from_array(np.zeros((8, 8, 3)), interpretation="rgb")
    print("step 2")
    res = np.asarray(image)
    print("step 3")
    return res

def main(nbpool):
    srcrange = range(2)
    if nbpool == 0:
        res = list()
        for srcid in srcrange:
            res.append(myfunction(srcid))
        return res
    else:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(nbpool)
        return pool.map(myfunction, srcrange)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res1 = main(0)
    print("Now with multiprocessing")
    res2 = main(1)
```

Please note that using the 'spawn' start method can cause your program to run slower, as a new Python interpreter has to be created for each child process. However, it can help avoid issues with forking in environments like IPython or Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: You seem to be right. I managed to solve the issue with Lucas M. Uriarte suggestion, and also with your `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` line. But to avoid a "Context has already been set" error I had to use try: / line / except RuntimeError: / pass

Comment: To avoid the "Context has already been set" error with `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`, check if the context is already set:
`import multiprocessing
if multiprocessing.get_start_method(allow_none=True) != 'spawn':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`
This ensures the start method is 'spawn', avoiding the error if it's already set.